# Adding ArcGIS Online vector tile service in Leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet, data, arcgis-online, web-service, vector-tiles

I am trying to add an arcgis online served vector tiles service to a Leaflet map. I am using ( https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid ) to add the vector tiles to a Leaflet v1.3.1 map application.

I am able to add ESRI layers into the Leaflet map using the following simplified code:

```
var esriTilesUrl = "https://basemaps.arcgis.com/v1/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap/VectorTileServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf";

var esriTilesPbfLayer = L.vectorGrid.protobuf(esriTilesUrl);

esriTilesPbfLayer.addTo(map);
```

However, when I try to add my arcgis online vector tiles to the leaflet map using the same code

```
var esriTilesUrl =  "https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/l4TwMwwoiuEVRPw9/arcgis/rest/services/CaryHouseHolds/VectorTileServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf";    

var esriTilesPbfLayer = L.vectorGrid.protobuf(esriTilesUrl);

esriTilesPbfLayer.addTo(map);
```

I get the following error:

GET https://tiles.arcgis.com/tiles/l4TwMwwoiuEVRPw9/arcgis/rest/services/CaryHouseHolds/VectorTileServer/tile/13/3222/2303.pbf 404 ()

What is the correct url to use to consume arcgis online vector tiles?

Comment: Still not working for you?  As of today, works for me using an ArcGIS Online Vector Tile layer.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest referencing [Esri Leaflet](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/) in general for leaflet and Esri related code.

In regards to the [Esri Vector Tile Layer](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/layers/vector-layer.html) You can use this option and construct.

> Constructor:
>   L.esri.Vector.layer( id, ,  options)
>
> Description:
>   key refers to the specific vector tile layer you'd like to add.
>
> L.esri.Vector.Layer is used to display vector tile services and attributes data providers appropriately.
>
> Options
>   `L.esri.Vector.Layer` accepts all  options.
>
> Methods
>   L.esri.Vector.Layer` inherits all methods from.
>
> Example
>   `<script src="./esri-leaflet-vector.js"></script>
>   var map = L.map('map').setView([37.75,-122.45], 12);
>   L.esri.Vector.layer('bd505ce3efff479bb4e87b182f180159').addTo(map);`

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am able to load the example 'bd505ce3efff479bb4e87b182f180159' just fine.  However when I try to load my tiles: L.esri.Vector.layer('3c41cfb096844078a44adfe57819464a').addTo(map); I get a bunch of mapbox-gl.js errors.  My arcgis online item is: http://carync.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=3c41cfb096844078a44adfe57819464a so I'm assuming that my key is '3c41cfb096844078a44adfe57819464a' . Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, that's correct ID.

Comment: is there something that need to be done in the ArcGIS Online side to make these vector tiles available to a leaflet app?

Comment: Are you able to post your full code?

Comment: The application is very large with many dependencies. I'll try to make an example this afternoon and post a link later today.

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work in codepen. codepen is blocking the http request to the esri vector tiles.

Comment: I'm curious why L.esri.Vector.layer('bd505ce3efff479bb4e87b182f180159').addTo(map); works and L.esri.Vector.layer('3c41cfb096844078a44adfe57819464a').addTo(map);  does not. I'll post back if I figure this out.

Comment: Yea sure thing, keep in mind, if this question is answered and you have a different one, be sure to close this one out and start a new thread that way others can view the thread and try to answer the specific question.